# Find lowest value in range

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-api, range, google-sheets-api

My issue today is that I'm defining a function which will obtain the smallest value in a range of cells from another spreadsheet. My issue is that I'm not sure what kind of a comparison to pass, as what I have makes sense to me. But when I pass it, I'm receiving 1011 where the smallest number I have on the sheet is 925.

I pasted my code below, but I'm not sure where the problem lies.

```
function getOrder(num) 
    {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var s = ss.getSheetByName("parsed data");
      var myRange = s.getRange("C:C").getValues();
      var i=0;
      while(myRange[i]!="#VALUE!")
      {
      EDIT***if(num >= myRange[i].parseInt)
        {
           num = myRange[i];
        }
        else
        {} 
        i++
      }
      return num;
    }
```

Any thoughts?

thanks,
Alexander

Answer (score -1):

You are probably comparing string instead of numbers.

Before comparing these numbers, parse then with `parseDouble` or `parseInt`.

For example:

```
var a = 1011 < 965;      // (a = false)
var b= '1011' < '965';   // (b = true)
```

The difference is what you are comparing.

Comment: A downvote with no reason... By tthe time of my answer, there was no assurance that the comparing values were numbers.